# Restart single process with Foreman

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreman

I've been using foreman for a while now to scale my various ruby processes in a centralized manner, and it is working perfectly for me .

Anyways I would like to have some feature to restart a process or even to give it more control like to kill a process and start it again, in the current implementation when I kill one process the whole process in the main foreman stop . any workaround or solution here  ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: WONTFIX https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/issues/441

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that answer within the fork of John Mosses foreman_restartable , https://github.com/jmoses/foreman

Comment: Anyways I want my processes to keep working even if one down , is there any tricky way to restart the process or even not to stop all the processes in case one went down ? I mean in production level I want the solution to be stable enough, is that possible without Upstart ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

While `foreman start` is very convenient for development, I would not recommend it for production. I recommend using upstart, but there are also other alternatives - foreman also supports exporting to bluepill, inittab and runit (I've never used any of these myself).

I've also used [god](http://godrb.com/) in the past, and it worked quite well for starting and monitoring processes. I wrote a [foreman_god](https://github.com/embarkmobile/foreman_god) gem to use Procfiles with god, which simplifies the configuration (no need to export any config files).

Alternatively, there is also an [export script](https://github.com/otherinbox/foreman-export-god) that exports god config files from your Procfile.