# How to simply stop or restart foreman processes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreman

We have rails app that is running some foreman processes with `bundle exec foreman start`, and have googled a lot of different things, and found that the common suggestion is to set up another background process handler, and export the processes there.  So essentially let someone else do foreman's job of managing the processes.

My question is how do you simply stop or restart foreman processes, as I don't really want to try to export the processes to another manager.

Shouldn't there be a simple: `foreman restart`

Since there is a: `foreman start`

Is there a snippet or some other command that anyone has used to restart these processes?

Any help or explanation of the foreman tool would be appreciated.

Comment: single process stop http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587588/restart-single-process-with-foreman is WONTFIX https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/issues/441 , so I imagine this is too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used monit to control stop and start of foreman processes.